# Log4net configuration is not working in production doe azure web services

Tags: c#, log4net, azure-web-app-service, log4net-configuration

I am using log4net for logging in my webapi. logging is working fine in my localhost or while i am deploying it on a app server. Same thing is not working in azure web service. Folder where log file has to be created is there but no files in there.
i have added below section in my web.config file,

```
<log4net>
<appender name ="ErrorLog" type ="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value ="MyLogs\"/>
  <staticLogFileName value ="false" />
  <appendToFile value ="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value ="Date"/>
  <datePattern value ="yyyy-MM-dd.'Err'" />
  <lockingModel type ="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <layout type ="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value ="%d{DATE} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<logger name ="ErrorLog">
  <maximumFileSize value ="15MB" />
  <appender-ref ref="ErrorLog"/>
</logger>
</log4net>
```

Comment: can you please add config file code as well as your code which add entry to log file?

Comment: @Mitesh, I have added the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there are some mistake with log4net configuration.

Here I have a complete steps you could follow with and it works well on my site:

1.Install the `log4net.dll` binary using NuGet.

2.Configure the log4net name, type properties in the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

3.Configure the log4net properties

```
<log4net>
   <root>
     <level value="Debug"/>
     <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
   </root>
   <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
     <param name="File" value="D:\Home\LogFiles\Log4Net\Log4Net.log"/>
     <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
     <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
     <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
     <maximumFileSize value="3MB"/>
     <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
     <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>
   <logger name="SleepyCore">
     <level value="INFO"/>
   </logger>
 </log4net>
```

**Note**: You need to specify the address of the log on azure like `D:\Home`

4.Modify the Global.asax Application_Start() method add the following code in the method.

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config")));
```

5.Write log with an instance of the ILog interface

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("SleepyCore");
            log.Info("Begin - Page_Load() at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff"));
```

6.The output as below:

[image]
[image]

For more details about how to configure log4net on azure, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/09/27/how-to-configure-log4net-on-azure-app-service/).

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Problem was with the path i guess. still, i want to give file name as current date. How i can add that with the code that you provided?